# SQL JOIN with CASE statement result

Tags: sql, join, case

Is there any way of joining the result of a case statement with a reference table without creating a CTE, ect.

Result **AFTER** CASE statement:

```
ID   Name   Bonus Level (this is the result of a CASE statement)
01   John     A
02   Jim      B
01   John     B
03   Jake     C
```

Reference table

```
A   10%
B   20%
C   30%
```

I want to then get the % next to each employee, then the max %age using the MAX function and grouping by ID, then link it back again to the reference so that each employee has the single correct (highest) bonus level next to their name. (This is a totally fictitious scenario, but very similar to what I am looking for).

Just need help with joining the result of the CASE statement with the reference table. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please show us the *original* data, your expected output, and your current query ?

Comment: It looks like *instead* of a case statement, you want a join. If you join with the appropriate `ON` clause, you'll join A 10% to John, so no need for a `CASE` construct anymore.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? If you go for `SQL in general` - which version of SQL you are targeting? SQL-89, SQL-92, SQL-2003?

Comment: You mention CTE so it must SQL-1999 at least. MSSQL/Oracle/PostgreSQL/last versions of MySQL?

Comment: (1) What is the aversion to a CTE?  (2) Can you provide sample data and desired results?  (3) Tag with the database you are using.  (4) What is "age"?

Comment: The CASE statement is very convoluted, but is giving me the correct output. I need the result in the CASE statement to link with a reference table and was wondering if there was a way around it other than using a CTE. Thanks for everyone's help. I think i'll use a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

In place of a temporary value as the result of the case statement, you could use a select statement from the reference  table.

So if your case statement looks like:

```
case  when variable1=value then bonuslevel =A
```

Then, replacing it like this might help

```
case when variable1=value then (select percentage from ReferenceTable where variable2InReferenceTable=A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I am overly simplifying, but based on the results of your case result query, why not just join that to the reference table, and do a max grouped by ID/Name.  Since the ID and persons name wont change anyhow since they are the same person, you are just getting the max you want.  To complete the Bonus level, rejoin just that portion after the max percentage determined for the person.

```
select
      lvl1.ID,
      lvl1.Name,
      lvl1.FinalBonus,
      rt2.BonusLvl
   from
      ( select
              PQ.ID,
              PQ.Name,
              max( rt.PcntBonus ) as FinalBonus
           from
              (however you 
                  got your 
                  data query ) PQ
                 JOIN RefTbl rt
                    on PQ.BonusLvl = rt.BonusLvl
       ) lvl1
          JOIN RefTbl rt2
             on lvl1.FinalBonus = rt2.PcntBonus
```

Since the Bonus levels (A,B,C) do not guarantee corresponding % levels (10,20,30), I did it this way... OTHERWISE, you could have just used max() on both the bonus level and percent.  But what if your bonus levels were listed as something like

```
Limited    10%
Aggressive 20%
Ace        30%
```

You could see that a max of the level above would have "Limited", but the max % = 30 is associated with an "Ace" sales rep...  Get the 30% first, then see what the label that matched that is.